# Outlook VBA .Restrict Uses Work Hours

Tags: vba, outlook, restrict

When I use restrict to set the date range on an Outlook item object, it does not pick up any appointments before whatever I have set as my "Work Hours" on Outlook. How do I make whatever the user sets as "Work Hours" not influence my macro?

Eg. My "Work Hours" in Outlook is set to 1PM to 5PM. I create 4 appointments:

- 1111 at 10AM Sept 4, 2017
- 2222 at 1PM Sept 4, 2017
- 3333 at 6PM Sept 4, 2017
- 4444 at 1PM Sept 5, 2017

My code will pick up the last 3 appointments, but not the first, if the dates I enter are 9/4/2017 and 9/5/2017.

```
Sub restrictDemo()

Dim olkItems As Outlook.Items, _
    olkSelected As Outlook.Items, _
    olkAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem, _
    dateStart As Date, _
    dateEnd As Date

dateStart = InputBox("Starting date?", "", "m/d/yyyy")
dateEnd = InputBox("Ending date?", "", "m/d/yyyy")

If IsDate(dateStart) And IsDate(dateEnd) Then

    Set olkItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items
    olkItems.IncludeRecurrences = True
    olkItems.Sort "Start"
    Set olkSelected = olkItems.Restrict("[Start] >= '" & dateStart & "' AND [Start] <= '" & dateEnd & "'")

    For Each olkAppt In olkSelected
        counter = counter + 1
        MsgBox counter
        MsgBox olkAppt.Subject & " " & olkAppt.Location & olkAppt.Start
    Next

Else
    MsgBox "You must enter valid starting and ending dates to run this macro.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, MACRO_NAME
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: ok, so, what is your question?

Comment: What are the values of dateStart  and dateEnd? Keep in mind that hours is a part of the date/time value. You cannot have a restriction on hours alone without also specifying the date.

Comment: My question is how do I have the 'work hours' not affect this program. If I enter '9/4/2017' as the start and '9/5/2017', I want the range that it picks up to be '9/4/2017 12:00AM' to '9/5/2017 12:00AM'.

Comment: I enter '9/4/2017' and '9/5/2017' for dateStart and dateEnd respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Use the format expected by Restict.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/items-restrict-method-outlook

```
Sub restrictDemo()

    Dim Counter As Long

    Dim olkItems As items
    Dim olkSelected As items
    Dim olkAppt As AppointmentItem

    Dim dateStart
    Dim dateEnd

    Dim StrFilter As String

    ' You may need to use a different date format.
    dateStart = InputBox("Starting date?", , "2017-08-22")
    dateEnd = InputBox("Ending date?", , "2017-08-23")

    If IsDate(dateStart) And IsDate(dateEnd) Then

        Set olkItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).items
        olkItems.IncludeRecurrences = True
        olkItems.Sort "Start"

        'StrFilter = "[Start] >= '" & dateStart & "' AND [Start] < '" & dateEnd & "'"
        'Debug.Print StrFilter

        StrFilter = "[Start] >= '" & Format(dateStart, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
        Debug.Print StrFilter

        StrFilter = StrFilter & " AND [Start] < '" & Format(dateEnd, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
        Debug.Print StrFilter

        Set olkSelected = olkItems.Restrict(StrFilter)

        For Each olkAppt In olkSelected
            Counter = Counter + 1
            Debug.Print Counter & ":" & olkAppt.Subject & " " & olkAppt.location & olkAppt.start
            'MsgBox Counter & ":" & olkAppt.Subject & " " & olkAppt.location & olkAppt.start
        Next

    Else
        MsgBox "Enter valid starting and ending dates.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "MACRO_NAME"

    End If

End Sub
```

The deeper question of why a day begins at the start of a work day and continues for 24 hours remains unanswered.

Comment: Yes. In other words, you need to pass explicitly the time in the restrict start and end date else without time Outlook starts (or ends) when your work day does.